# Parse python module installtion for python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

Can somebody let me know how to install python "parse" module for python2.7 version?

Server details :
CloudLinux Server release 5.11
cPanel 54.0 (build 21)

Comment: isn't it just the same as installing any other module?

Answer (score 1):

If you have pip installed, try to run `pip install parse` as root.

Comment: My server have python2.4 and python2.7 how I can install it for python2.7. Installing it with pip will support both python?